# Guest use receive error No profiling information for SOQL operations

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

Guest user receives an error after pressing redirect button in VFP

```
14:55:47.2 (40002254)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|VF: /apex/dossierattachmentsform
14:55:47.2 (40024393)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
14:55:47.43 (43470627)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING_BEGIN
14:55:47.43 (43470627)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling information for SOQL operations
14:55:47.43 (43470627)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling information for SOSL operations
14:55:47.43 (43470627)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling information for DML operations
14:55:47.43 (43470627)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|method invocations|
External entry point: public void <init>(ApexPages.StandardController): executed 1 time in 30 ms
Class.DossierAttachmentsExtension.<init>: line 16, column 1: global SObject getRecord(): executed 0 times in 0 ms
```

In this method

```
public with sharing class DossierAttachmentsExtension {

    public  Dossier__c dossier {
         get {
            if (dossier == null) {
                dossier = new Dossier__c ();
            }

            return dossier;
        } set;
    }

    public List<Winput> inputs{get;set;}

    public DossierAttachmentsExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        dossier = (Dossier__c)controller.getRecord();
        dossier = [Select Id, Name from Dossier__c where Id = :dossier.Id];

        inputs = new List<Winput>();
    }
```

From the user side we have this error for the second step where we try attaching documents
[image]

Thank you. Realy didn't find the answer.

visual force pages and apex classes can be accessed by the site user

Log level
[image]

Comment: Is this really an error that your users are seeing? or is it only coming up in your debug log? What are your debug log levels?

Comment: @DerekF Thx for the response - debug level is Finest (max). This error is located in debug log for Guest User with Guest User License. Users see a page with Authorization Required

You must first log in or register before accessing this page.
If you have forgotten your password, click Forgot Password to reset it. *already add to main topic

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that information. Also, there is more than one debug type. There's DB, Callouts, ApexCode, Validation, Workflow, Profiling, Visualforce, System, Wave, and Nba. Knowing what your log level for _all_ of those will probably be helpful.

Comment: @DerekF Pls take a look at the last prtscr

Comment: why are you constructing `dossier` twice?  the `getRecord()` should be sufficient.

Comment: Does it work when a non-guest user performs the same steps?

Comment: @DanielHoechst Unfortunately Yes

Comment: You say the problem is when the user clicks the redirect button. I don't see any code that looks like it would be executed in that case. Is there more code you can share?

Comment: @DanielHoechst currently I have a problem in the controller's constructor - this line  dossier = (Dossier__c)controller.getRecord(); throw this error 14:55:47.43 (43470627)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling information for SOQL operations
14:55:47.43 (43470627)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling information for SOSL operations
14:55:47.43 (43470627)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling information for DML operations

Comment: Those aren't errors. If it were an error, you'd see an exception message.